# NodeMCU: Wiegand not working for one device, while working for another

Tags: nodemcu, rfid, rs485, rs232

I'm using a NodeMCU, and a working code for reading Wiegand data, with [this library](https://github.com/paulo-raca/YetAnotherArduinoWiegandLibrary).

I managed to successfully read the Wiegand signal from [this device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32888710502.html).

However, I also have this [new AR-721H device](http://www.soyal.com/product.php?act=view&id=23), and I can't get the Wiegand to work. This is the [manual for the device](http://www.soyal.com/data/files/download/manual/321H-331H-721H-725H-757H-en.pdf).

There is absolutely nothing coming to the mcu. Everything is wired identically as the working device.

According to the manual, everything should be working, but I am at a loss.

**Can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong?**

The store clerk told me something about needing a controller that converts RS485 to RS232, but I have no idea what that means. I already made it work with another device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite cryptic from the little information in that (somewhat chaotic) "manual", but I interpret it that the Wiegand interface is an *input* port, not an *output* port.  It is intended to connect that port to an external card reader or keypad as a remote interface (typically the other side of the door to this unit).

For communication with your Arduino you should use the RS-485 interface. For that you need an MAX485 breakout board.

Comment: I suspect that the store clerk was talking about using RxTx for the data transmission, available in [this device](http://www.soyal.com/data/files/download/manual/727H-V5-en.pdf). He said all the programmers bought a controller to convert the signal, and I think he doesn't know what he's talking about, since the device I bought uses Wiegand, as an input at that as you said. I didn't understand your last sentence about `MAX485` tho...

Comment: RS485 is a specific electrical signalling format for UART (serial) data. You need to convert that to UART using a MAX485 - then you can feed it in to the TX/RX pins (or other pins using SoftwareSerial) and communicate using Serial. You'd need to know the baud rate and protocol though to make sense of the data.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. In other words, the clerk is clueless... As the device I bought doesn't even have the option to use UART.

Comment: @Ivan Yes it does (or should have) - P3 is the RS-485 port.

Comment: @Ivan I can tell you that it should be running at 9600 baud - but what the data content will be I haven't managed to discern.

Comment: @Ivan Pay Dirt! https://kupdf.net/download/721-727h-protocol-en_5bfba826e2b6f5d51b0dabd5_pdf

Comment: Ok, so we've established that I am the stupid one. No problem. So the NodeMCU has RxTx pins (RS232), but that won't work with the RS485 directly (which I failed to see, thanks for that) i.e. I'd need a hardware converter as he said. Correct? Can I do this with software?

Comment: You need a MAX485 breakout board.  AR-721H <-> MAX485 <-> ESP8266. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485

Comment: I see... Thanks for the elaboration. I am really stupid with this stuff, and I am trying to learn. Can you please tell me what the MAX485 board does? Does it just do the conversion? I can't figure it out from Googling.

Comment: You're not stupid - you just don't have this area of knowledge yet. In one mode the MAX485 chip takes normal UART data in one side and spits out the RS485 equivalent from the other. In the other mode it receives RS485 data in one side and spits out UART data out the other. You switch modes with the DE and RI pins (which you can connect to the same GPIO pin of the ESP8266).  It's basically a transparent bridge between UART and RS485 that runs in the direction you specify. In TX mode you can `Serial.write(...)` data. In RX mode you can `Serial.read()` data.

Comment: @Ivan Actually since you're working at 3.3V you need the MAX**3**485 since it's the 3.3V version.

Comment: @Ivan I'm trying to update my answer with a diagram for you, but the schematic editor is being a complete arse.

Comment: I could also use a [level converter](https://5.imimg.com/data5/UL/XU/MY-9380557/5v-to-3-3v-logic-level-converter-500x500.jpg) with the `MAX485`, instead of the `MAX3485`, correct?

Comment: @Ivan Sure, but that gets messy then.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of wiring. I am so frustrated that I can't find a simple RFID reader with a keypad... It's either devices without keypads working with Wiegand, or the ones with Wiegand having all sorts of weird workarounds... Why is the access control area so complicated?

Comment: @Ivan https://www.supremainc.com/en/hardware/compact-outdoor-rfid-reader-xpass-d2.asp

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are specifically recommending these?

Comment: It's one I just happen to be aware of. I should have one coming some time for a job I am working on at the moment. I'll know more about working with them when the customer finally sends me one.